# SQL server management studio Projects folder

Tags: sql-server

Is there any easy way of changing the SQL Server Management Studio default 'Project' folder?  I found one registry hack on the internet, but I'd rather not bother with that.

I'm using SQL Server 2005 Express.

Comment: Since I wrote this and really didn't get a solution, I've settled on a compromise: each time I need a new project folder, I set up a folder where I want it and then put a shortcut to this folder into the SSMS default folder - adds one click to a Save, but keeps my SQL files nicely organized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like it. There is no way of doing it from the options in management studio. You need to edit the paths stored in the registry at:

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ShellSEM`

Comment: How annoying. It seems like an obvious thing to have an editable option for.  I really don't want to be messing with the registry on a client's computer.  Thanks to both of you - if nobody's come up with a better solution by tomorrow, I guess I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

Registry Location on my machine:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell**

I modified the **DefaultFileOpenLocation** key to change where my open file dialogue points to.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/changing-ssms-and-visual-studio-default-project-location/) you can do it by changing an config file as well.

Comment: I found the setting in the config file, and when I change the folder, SSME shows a 'configuring....' warning message when it loads.  But it still doesn't change the default folder.  Strange.

Answer (score 0):

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\10\Tools\Shell

Did not work for me so I keept looking under Shell reg directory and noticed the whole setting menu (found on visual studio) change the LocalProjectLocationEntry1 at below location and the above enties will be overwritten

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\General\ProjectLocationEntries